# Value of the dropdown changes, but doesnt reflect in dropdown till reload using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of dropdowns on which I am setting filters and storing it to local storage. Now I am trying to do an individual reset on the filters. If I change the value of the particular ng-model like

```
$scope.filters[0]['value'] = null
```

or even if i change to a diffrent value like

```
$scope.filters[0]['value'] = 3
```

The data gets results get reset and the value changes in the controller, however, it doesn't reflect in the drop-down till reload the page. I am guessing it has some link to the local storage I am setting. Please suggest.

My code snippet

HTML

```
<select ng-model="filters[0]['value']" class="labs_select fix-width-input select2 select_tab_inner" placeholder="Select Task Type" ng-options="taskType.id as taskType.name for taskType in taskTypes" class="dynamic_attributes">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select Task Type</option>
</select> 
<button btn btn-default ng-click="removeFilter(filters[0]['value'])" class="reset-button" id="reset-attribute1"> x </button>
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.removeFilter = (value) ->
  $scope.filterApplied = false
  $scope.filters[0]['value'] = null
```

The value changes and the results get filtered accordingly. But the value in dropdown doesnt change

Comment: Provide your code please.

Comment: try calling `$scope.apply();` to update the view.

Comment: I have updated with the code

Comment: What value you want to be preselected in the dropdown?

Comment: @Envision it says $scope.apply is not a function. Am i missing something?

Comment: Preselected is a default select type text

Comment: Try $scope.$apply() @PallaviHegde

Comment: sorry it's `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: it says $apply already in progress(…)

Comment: If I try this jquery function in console it sets to null $('#task_type_filter').select2("val",2). Is there something like this which i can try?

Comment: Try $scope.$watch($scope.filters[0]['value'],function(newval){console.log(newval); })